# Error when running jest on a react native + typescript app (Jest encountered an unexpected token)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs

It seems like everyone and their mother are having a variation of this problem. Nothing worked from everything I have tried from all the SO questions and GH tickets.

It should actually be quite simple, since my project is pretty much a new barebone project. Yet I still can't figure out what is wrong for the life of me.

When I run `jest`:

```
/Desktop/Dropbox/Programming/iphone-app/fe/App.spec.tsx:11
    const tree = react_test_renderer_1.default.create(<App_1.default />).toJSON();
                                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

My config files:

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

-

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

-

```
// babel.config.js

module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    };
};
```

**EDIT #1**

Just to be clear, I have tried using the `react-native` preset in the jest config file, with no success (same error):

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    preset: 'react-native',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js',
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json'
        }
    },
    testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with this config file:

```
const { defaults } = require('jest-config');

module.exports = {
    preset: 'react-native',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js',
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'tsx',
        ...defaults.moduleFileExtensions
    ],
};
```

I needed to add

```
...
moduleFileExtensions: [
    'tsx',
    ...defaults.moduleFileExtensions
],
...
```

Or else the `import App from './App';` in my test would resolve to some other file. By adding `tsx` as the topmost priority in the `moduleFileExtensions` option, the app resolves the correct file.

Also the `jsx` compiler option in `tsconfig.json` needs to be set to `"jsx": "react"`. I'm not sure why I can't set it to `react-native` yet, but everything seems to work for now.

**EDIT**

`'^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js'` is not needed in newer versions of `react-native`. [Keeping it may also cause a problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814268/how-to-mock-a-third-party-react-native-component-with-jest)

Comment: problem persisted after attempting this solution

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problems are opening and closing. Can you try editing your code as follows?

```
import 'react-native'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { App } from './app'
import React from 'react'

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <App />
  )
  expect(tree).toBeDefined()
})
```